# How to add more items at the bottom of an Android Array-backed ListView, and keep position?

Tags: android

I have a ListView with an ArrayAdapter providing the data. I'm adding paging, so when you scroll to the bottom it loads more rows.

But as I'm using an array I'm finding a problem. I can't extend the array as the size is obviously fixed, and if I create a new one, the ListView either ignores the new items (notifyDataSetChanged), or (if I refresh the list with the new array) it jumps to the top.

What's the usual way to do this? Use a different collection type? Use a large array with capacity for the maximum number of rows? Or is there a way to notify an adapter the dataset has changed and it actually works (notifyDataSetChanged() is not working in my scenario, probably because the array hasn't just changed, it's a completely different one, so the notify is probably working with the old one). Or should I set the adapter up with the new larger array, and jump it to the right position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say ArrayList in the title, but you're talking about just an Array. Try using an ArrayList, you can add as many items as you need to with the `ArrayList.add()` method. Am I misunderstanding you, maybe?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'm using an array. I need type-safety and would like to avoid casting every time I put/remove from the collection. Best to subclass ArrayList, rather than using an array?

Comment: I don't really have a good answer for that, unfortunately. ArrayList is what I would use in this instance. Subclassing it instead...I'll leave that to someone else to answer. :)

Comment: Curious, also, why would you have to cast when adding it to the ArrayList? You can just create it as an ArrayList<ObjectType>.

Comment: Yes, you're right, no need to cast. ArrayList looks fine, though there's no ArrayListAdapter, is there a suitable pre-built adapter, or do I need to roll my own. Thx

Comment: Yep, sure is. ArrayAdapter actually takes in Lists as well as typical arrays. If you check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List<T>) there are two different constructors that can take in a list.

Comment: I moved everything across to a ArrayList<MyClass> and it works well - adding items to the colelction then calling notifyDataSetChanged() does the job. The only hiccup was that the GSON method I use to populate the collection doesn't work with my generic type, so I'm pulling it into an array, the copy to the ArrayList - a little messy, but it works. Thx.

Comment: You're welcome. You could always use a direct JSONObject/JSONArray method rather than using GSON (I've not used JSON for a while, but it seems like it was fairly straightforward). But yeah, your way should work too.